# Как исправить ошибку ORA-01843 при импорте данных из xls-файла?

Tags: oracle, plsql, xls, plsql-developer

Имеется xls-файл большого объёма, который необходимо импортировать в БД. Работаю в PL/SQL Developer 12. Предварительно создал в БД пустую таблицу, для чего использовал два варианта запроса:

Сначала такой:

```
CREATE TABLE vz_117390_in_garant ( 
  COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(38),     /*--1 № дог.*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN5 DATE,             /*--5 Дата заключения договора*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN12 TIMESTAMP,       /*-12 Дата установки*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN28 NUMBER(38, 4),   /*-28 Мощность максимальная*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN38 VARCHAR2(128))   /*-38 Примечание*/
;
```

Когда не получилось, то такой:

```
CREATE TABLE vz_117390_in_garant ( 
  COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(38),   /*--1 № дог.*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN5 VARCHAR2(10),   /*--5 Дата заключения договора*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN12 VARCHAR2(19),  /*-12 Дата установки*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN28 VARCHAR2(38),  /*-28 Мощность максимальная*/
  ... ... ...
  COLUMN38 VARCHAR2(128)) /*-38 Примечание*/
;
```

Импорт пытался делать двумя способами:

1. Путём непосредственного копирования из excel-файла прямо в таблицу в режиме редактирования (с учётом того, что для правильного копирования из xls-таблицы в неё надо обязательно добавить левую колонку с порядковыми номерами строк);
2. С помощью инструмента в PL/SQL Developer - ODBC Importer.

В итоге при любом способе получаю сообщение такого типа:
[image: Снимок экрана PL/SQL Developer с ошибкой ORA-01843 при импорте инструментом ODBC Importer]

Пытался бороться такими способами:

1. Устанавливал параметр NLS_DATE_FORMAT:

   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY';
2. Заменял в исходном файле формат ячеек с "Общий" на "Текстовый";
3. Использовал в БД вместо первого варианта запроса (см. выше) второй с целью исключить использование типа данных "DATE".

Однако ничего не изменилось. Прошу подсказать ответ на вопрос топика.

Comment: Разделите импорт из Excel и вставку данных в таблицу. На первом этапе импортируйте данные во временную таблицу, с типами полей, которые гарантированно примут значение (VARCHAR2 гарантированно достаточной длины для каждого поля, и можно не стесняться). А на втором этапе копируйте данные из временной таблицы в постоянную, преобразуя текстовое значение в значение требуемого типа соответствующим выражением, с учётом исходного формата. Заодно верифицируйте данные на предмет любых проблем. То есть два или три запроса в рамках одной процедуры. И диагностика на выходе.

Comment: Где находится .xls файл?

Comment: @0xdb, xls-файл на локальной машине.

Comment: Не совсем понятны трудности, которые у вас возникли. Обычная же отладка, которую, судя по данным в вопросе, вы даже не попытались произвести. Какой ответ тогда вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: @0xdb, трудность в том, что при использовании, хоть, copy-paste, хоть ODBC Importer: во-первых, не видно на какую из колонок жалуется PL/SQL Developer; во-вторых, не понятно, почему он вообще на них жалуется, т.к. формат, в котором представлены даты в соответствующих колонках, по крайней мере визуально, выглядит корректно.

Comment: А вы не пробовали импортировать документ всего с одной ячейкой с датой, т.е. с одной колонкой и одной строкой, что получилось?

Comment: А не пробовали сохранить XLS как CSV (Excel это умеет), и дальше пробовать различные варианты импорта средствами Oracle - вроде SQL*Loader, или External Table. Тогда вместо графического интерфейса, в котором как Вы говорите, "даже непонятно на какое поле он ругается", у Вас будет полный контроль конвертации каждого поля. И можно будет проблемное поле с датой потестировать со всякими вариантами функции TO_DATE, подставляя разные маски/форматы исходных данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Положительный результат удалось получить после подсказки в первом комменте топика следующим путём:

1. Заменить в исходном xls-файле форматы всех ячеек на листе только на "Текстовый";
2. Выполнить второй запрос (см. формулировку вопроса);
3. Включить режим редактирования созданной на 2-м шаге таблицы;
4. Скопировать строки из исходного xls-файла через буфер обмена прямо в таблицу (с учётом того, что для правильного копирования из xls-таблицы в неё надо обязательно добавить левую колонку с порядковыми номерами строк);
5. Дать команду commit для записи данных в таблицу;
6. Выйти из режима редактирования таблицы.